# building jahia from source, having problems

Tags: java, maven-2, open-source, build-process, maven-1

I am trying to build jahia from source for a project at school. From the instructions online, all I seem to find to run is

```
maven install
```

which fails... any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A bit more information would be helpfull.
maven is a maven 1 build command
mvn is the maven 2 build command
Could you 
- add the output and
- if you have a pom.xml use mvn (maven2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Jahia is a Maven 2 project, the command you posted, "maven install", is the command for building with Maven 1.

To use Maven 2, you need to run the "mvn install" command. For details on installing Maven 2 check out the [installation section of the Maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/installation.html).

The Jahia pom defines a repositories section, so should be able to access all the required dependencies.

If you have problems running the mvn command, please update your question with the build trace.